# How To Convert This Format JSON to NSMutableArray

Tags: ios, objective-c, json

I'm writing a program that reads the website image data (from a database table), returns JSON format to IOS

I get a piece of code used to display images in iOS image view. He is written directly through to the value

```
self.images=@[
          @{@"category":@"Category A",
            @"images":
              @[
                 @{@"name":@"sample_1.jpg",@"title":@"A-0"},
                 @{@"name":@"sample_2.jpg",@"title":@"A-2"},
                 @{@"name":@"sample_3.jpg",@"title":@"A-3"}
               ]
              },
          @{@"category":@"Category B",
            @"images":
              @[
                 @{@"name":@"sample_5.jpg",@"title":@"B-0"},
                 @{@"name":@"sample_6.jpg",@"title":@"B-2"},
                 @{@"name":@"sample_7.jpg",@"title":@"B-3"}
               ]
              }
            ];

 [self.tableView reloadData];
```

I have two questions:

1. How to use JSON format and output return above the return value to 
   self.images
2. How to put these in an `NSMutableArray`

Many thanks

Comment: Read the documentation for the class NSJSONSerialization. If there's anything you don't understand, feel free to ask.

Comment: Your question is also very unclear. It is often helpful to yourself to turn your problem into a clear, understandable question - many times, asking a precise question will actually lead you directly to the answer.

Comment: Go to json.org and learn the JSON syntax.  It takes 5-10 minutes.

Comment: (Basically, to create the JSON, just take out the `@` characters above.  But remember, of course, that if you put this into a string you must escape the quotes.  Or, if you want to start with the above and produce JSON, use NSJSONSerialization.)